# Inject an environment variable into a JPA Entity

Tags: jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I want to be able to inject a value from  ejb-jar.xml into a JPA Entity Listener. Is that possible? I am using the GlassFish 3.x server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injection is not supported for entity listeners in EE 6.  In EE 7, the JPA 2.1 spec states that entity listeners are CDI beans, which are eligible for injection.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the inject of <env-entry> environment variable from ejb-jar.xml

Comment: Now I use the method "context.lookup(JNDI_NAME)" to inject a session bean in my entiy listener.

Comment: There's no injection support, but yes, you can use JNDI to access the values. The disadvantage is that your entity listener becomes harder to unittest because it's reaching into its environment rather than having its environment injected into it.

Comment: Thank again, I will use the method of JNDI lookup with "java:comp/env/variable_name" to achieve my goal.